# Operations on Random Variables and expected values

Tags: probability, statistics

If we are given a random variable X with its own events and their respective probabilities, then how would you go about computing:
$$ E(X^2) , E(2X+1)^2 $$

Moreover, how would you solve this problem? I know how to compute the expected value , but what do I due to those manipulations?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a discrete distribution, $f(x_i)$, like in your example, you can use $E[g(X)] = \sum_i f(x_i) g(x_i)$.

EDIT: Since this worked for the OP, I thought I'd show the approach in detail for other readers.

$\newcommand\T{\Rule{0pt}{1em}{.3em}}
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
 x_i & -3 & 6 & 9  \\\hline
 f(x_i) & 1/6 & 1/2 & 1/3 \\\hline
 g(x_i) & 25 & 169 & 361 \\\hline
 f(x_i)g(x_i) & 25/6 & 169/2 & 361/3 \\
\end{array}$

So $E[g(X)]= 25/6 + 169/2 + 361/3 = 209$.

A second way to do it is to evaluate the moments and use the linearity referred to in the other answer:

$E[X] = 11/2$, $E[X^2]=93/2$ so $E[(2X+1)^2]=4E[X^2]+4E[X]+1=186+22+1=209$.

The second way is perhaps slightly slower in this example (evaluating $E[X^2]$ is similar to evaluating $E[g(X)]$), but often you need the moments anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** It is $$E[(2X+1)^2]=E[4X^2+4X+1]=4\cdot E[X^2]+4\cdot E[X]+1$$

And

$$E[X]=\sum_{x \in A} x\cdot P(X=x)$$

$$E[X^2]=\sum_{x \in A} x^2\cdot P(X=x)$$

$A=\{-3,6,9\}$

Comment: Oh I see! Are there any more rules to this I can look up?

Comment: First line: linearity of expectation. And $var(X)=E[x^2]-(E[x])^2$. So  look for variance.